# Vuex how to declare constant root mutations

Tags: ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuex, vue-tables-2

So I have a very similar Application Structure to the example below
https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/tree/dev/examples/shopping-cart

However, there is no root mutations defined there. I need to create one since I have to update the state that is dynamically created in vue-tables-2.

In my mutation-types.js I declared the name of the mutation as

```
export const UPDATE_CLIENTTABLE = 'UPDATE_CLIENTTABLE'
```

However, I'm not sure how to write the mutations in mutations.js There's no module defined because the state is dynamically created by vue-tables-2. I'm doing something like below but it doesn't work

```
[types.UPDATE_CLIENTTABLE] (state, data) {
    state.ClientTableLine.data = data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to export your mutation in your mutations.js file

```
export const [types.UPDATE_CLIENTTABLE) = (state, data) => {
  state.ClientTableLine.data = data
}
```

Then import it into your vuex set up

```
import * as mutations from './mutations'
export default new Vuex.Store({
  mutations,
  actions,
  getters,
  modules: {
    cart,
    products
  },
  strict: debug,
  plugins: debug ? [createLogger()] : []
})
```

This is assuming your vuex set up is taken from the shopping car example